# how to delete the nth occurrence of a character in a string bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string like this: `str="test,test,test,test,test,test"`. How can I delete the nth comma (,) in the string `str`, where `n` is between `1` and `5`?
Can anyone give any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ echo "$str"
test,test,test,test,test,test
$ sed 's/,//5' <<<"$str" #or echo "$str" |sed 's/,//5'
test,test,test,test,testtest
```

Comment: You can do `n=2` then `sed 's/,//'"$n"`

Comment: @dawg In this case, there's no need to use both single and double quotes, since there's nothing in the single-quoted part that is going to get expanded, or that would need to be escaped in a double-quoted string. So you can just do `sed "s/,//$n"`

Comment: @MikeHolt: Why even have to consider whether there is anything to expand in the `sed` script? There is no downside really to `sed 's/,//'"$n"` is there?

Comment: @dawg To each his own, I guess. To me there's a minor downside (slightly decreased readability) and no upside to mixing single and double quotes in this case. For such a short script, one can see at a glance that there's no expansion going on, so it just makes sense to me to write it as simply and cleanly as possible. Granted, this is a very minor nit to pick.

Answer (score 2):

I can give this a shot.

Without using any other tools other than just `echo` and parameter expansion, you can do something like:

```
$ str="test,test,test,test,test,test"
$ echo ${str:0:4}${str:5}
testtest,test,test,test,test

$ echo ${str:0:9}${str:10}
test,testtest,test,test,test

$ echo ${str:0:14}${str:15}
test,test,testtest,test,test

$ echo ${str:0:19}${str:20}
test,test,test,testtest,test

$ echo ${str:0:24}${str:25}
test,test,test,test,testtest
```

So, the idea is...

```
echo ${variable:0:[index before the comma]}${variable:[index of the comma]}
```

Obviously, I did more than just `5` like you stated but it was more for demonstration.  At this point, I would make the indices that you need as variables and feed in the value where the comma is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` solution:

```
$ echo "$str" | awk -v n=3 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} 
                      {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
                          printf "%s%s", $i, (i==n || i==NF) ? "" : OFS}'
test,test,testtest,test,test
```